# Suitescript: Can't Get Result From Search

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

The following is the script that I write for writing back "**ship from location"** information to Item Fulfillment for a certain customer. But it's not working.

Anyone see a syntax error, know what I might be missing, or what I can test for?

```
    case "2946":
        var warehousecode = WH_Code_Lookup(customer , location);
        itemfulfillment.setFieldValue('custbody_warehouse_code', warehousecode);// set warehouse code

        // Set Ship from location
        var columns = [];
        columns[0] = new nlobjSearchColumn('address1');
        columns[1] = new nlobjSearchColumn('address2');
        columns[2] = new nlobjSearchColumn('city');
        columns[3] = new nlobjSearchColumn('state');
        columns[4] = new nlobjSearchColumn('country');
        columns[5] = new nlobjSearchColumn('zip');

        var search = nlapiSearchRecord('location', null, new nlobjSearchFilter('internalid', null, 'is', invCheckFlag), columns);

        itemfulfillment.setFieldValue('custbodyship_from_address1', search[0].getValue('address1'));
        itemfulfillment.setFieldValue('custbodyship_from_address2', search[0].getValue('address2'));
        itemfulfillment.setFieldValue('custbodyship_from_city', search[0].getValue('city'));
        itemfulfillment.setFieldValue('custbodyship_from_country', search[0].getValue('country'));
        itemfulfillment.setFieldValue('custbodyship_from_state', search[0].getValue('state'));
        itemfulfillment.setFieldValue('custbodyship_from_postal_code', search[0].getValue('zip'));

        if(location == 6){
            itemfulfillment.setFieldValue('thirdpartyacctups',edi_customer_search[0].getValue('custrecord_2nd_3rd_pty_ups'));
            itemfulfillment.setFieldValue('thirdpartyzipcodeups',edi_customer_search[0].getValue('custrecord_2nd_3rd_pty_ups_zip'));
            itemfulfillment.setFieldValue('thirdpartytypeups','BILLTHIRDPARTY');
        }
        break;
```

Comment: Hello Jasmine, Welcome to Stackoverflow :)
can you explain what the problem is ?
Do you have any error showing in the console ?
Or no error but nothing happening ?
Please be more specific, for example "i am expecting this result but this error showing: xxxx"

Comment: What is `invCheckFlag`?

Comment: try `if (location === 6)`? Just trying to provide options.

Comment: Another question is where are you getting the itemfulfillment record from and how are you submitting it?

Answer (score 0):

You stated that the code doesn't work. Is there a specific error, as someone asked? Does the search bring back results or is it an issue in the search itself? Did you add any debug code in your script to see if you can pinpoint where the issue may be?